# When is a homomorphism an epimorphism?!

Tags: modules, abstract-algebra

I want to prove the following characterization of an $R$-module homomorphism $g$ to be surjective:

"*whenever the composition of $g:M→N$ and $k:N→Y$ is zero, then $k=0$*".

It is easy to go one side: if $g$ is surjective then for any $n\in N$ we have $n=g(m)$ for some $m\in M$. Now, if the composition is zero we would have $k(n)=k(g(m))=0$. But, for the converse, I could not choose suitable $Y$ and $k$. Thanks, in advance, for any cooperation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $g$ has the quoted property.
Let $Y = N/\text{im}(g)$ and $ k : N \rightarrow Y$ the natural projection. Then $k \circ g = 0$, so $k = 0$ by assumption. But $k$ is surjective, so we have to have $Y = 0$, hence $N = \text{im}(g)$ and so $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for answering. A similar situation characterizes $g:M→N$ to be a mono, i.e. whenever the composition of $h:X→M$ and $g:M→N$ is zero , then $h=0$. Now, From these observation, how could we deduce that $0→A→B→C→0$ being an exact sequence is a categorical property? In fact, if $F$ is a categorical equivalence from the category of right $R$-modules to the category of (say) right $S$-modules and $fog=0$ then $F(f)o F(g)=0$, so $ImF(g)⊆kerF(f)$. But how for the converse inclusion?

Comment: Notice that it is easy from the above characterization of mono and epi to see that kernels and cokernels are preserved by categorical equivalences, thus also images (which are kernels of cokernels). This allows you to calculate $\text{im}(F(g)) = F(\text{\im}(g)) = F(\ker(f)) = \ker(F(f))$.